# Web Crawling : Difficulty in finding required link using inspect element

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

I am a beginner to web crawling and I am using BeautifulSoup.
I was trying to crawl the page " https://www.codechef.com/rankings/ACMAMR15?filterBy=&order=asc&page=2&sortBy=rank "

(Visit the link for understanding the query)

I wanted the all the links like : "acm15am1235".
I tried using soup.findAll('a') , But couldn't recognise what type of tags to be passed in soup.findAll so as to get the required links.

Please indicate a method to capture required links.

Answer (score 0):

first You have to get all the divs containing the links

```
usernames = soup.find_all("div", class_="user-name")
```

next:

```
for username in usernames:
    print "link is :" + str(username.a['href'])
```